# How to compare performance among different keras models

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras

I have three different `keras` models namely `multi-scale CNN, single-scale CNN, shallow CNN` performing same task. I want to compare performance of these models. Almost every model achieved same accuracy in same time as I can see those graphs from model.history parameters like acc, val-acc. Now I want to specifically point out some differences among these models. Is there any way to observe the performance in much more detailed manner? and I want to make these graphs and I don't know how to plot them.

1. Model accuracy vs time
2. Model accuracy vs no.of input batches (my batch size is 5)

My CNN code is like this

```
def Single_Scale_Model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(20, (1, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', data_format='channels_first', input_shape=(19, 1, 50)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((1, 2), data_format='channels_first'))
    model.add(Conv2D(40, (1, 3), activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', data_format='channels_first'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((1, 2), data_format='channels_first'))
    model.add(Conv2D(60, (1, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', data_format='channels_first'))  
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((1, 3), data_format='channels_first'))
    model.add(Flatten(data_format='channels_first'))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

    #print(model.summary())
    model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

other two models are also like this but with a slight change in terms of number of layers

[image: Plots look same for both models(Model is meant to achieve 100% accuracy very fast.)]
Plots look same for both models(Model is meant to achieve 100% accuracy very fast.)

Comment: Can you post some of your CNN code for reference?

When I want to review models, I typically plot the loss and the accuracy. 

As an example, If the validation loss is increasing, while the validation accuracy is increasing, then your model is becoming more confident at making a poor fit.

It's possible the loss may reveal more details about your model.

Comment: @SeanPayne I tried plotting those graphs but almost every graph looks same. I was not able to distinguish on basis of those plots.

Comment: Your accuracy looks like it's at 100% for both training and test sets, so realistically speaking, you can't make observations about the differences in these models.

The best observation to make here is that the simplest model works just as well as a complicated one, so there is no advantage to using a more complicated model. As for providing additional details, I don't have anything for you.